# Why count function is working differently for the same input?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I was reading about the `COUNT()` function on Microsoft's official page, where I found this:

> Arguments that are numbers, dates, or a text representation of numbers (for example, a number enclosed in quotation marks, such as "1") are counted.

I dropped into Excel and entered a value in a cell : "1", which was treated as text by Excel and, therefore, aligned to the left in cell A1. I, then, tabbed to an adjacent cell and write a function referring to cell A1: `=COUNT($A$1)`, output
**0**. That means Excel doesn't count the value "1" as numeric.

Finally, as I was playing with the function, I write another function but this time give a value rather than a cell address to the `COUNT()` function: `=COUNT("1")`, output "1".

Above I referenced a statement from Microsoft's official page which says it also counts numbers represented as text. Contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

Not contradiction.

If you put `"1"` in the cell reads the literal `"` and as such it is a text string containing `"1"` and not a number `1` stored as text which is what the statement is referring to.

`1` stored as text looks like `1` in the cell but is text and not a number.  This COUNT() will count.

When you do the formula `=COUNT("1")` it is the same as the number being stored as text.

Having `"1"` in the cell is the same as `=COUNT("""1""")` which will return `0`

[image]

Put `="1"` in a cell and `="""1"""` and you will see `1` and `"1"` respectively.

When using a string in a formula one must put `""` around them.

For example in the cell you can put `Test` and use `=LEN(A1)` to return `4` but to use just the formula you need to do `=LEN("Test")` for the formula to work.

If you put `"Test"` in the cell the `LEN` will return `6` not `4`. Putting `"1"` in a cell is not the same as using `"1"` in a formula. It is `"""1"""`

Just to prove that `"1"` in a cell is the same as `"""1"""` in a formula:

[image]

Comment: I am glad you try to answer. But, the fact that two things have the same output doesn't make them the same thing. This logic doesn't hold.

Comment: It is the same thing.  Put `="1"` in a cell and `="""1"""` and you will see `1` and `"1"` respectively.  When using a string in a formula one must put `""` around them.  For example in the cell you can put `Test` and use `=LEN(A1)` to return `4` but to use just the formula you need to do `=LEN("Test")` for the formula to work.  If you put `"Test"` in the cell the `LEN` will return `6` not `4`.  Putting `"1"` in a cell is not the same as using `"1"` in a formula.  It is `"""1"""`

Comment: In support of Scott, VBA formulas require escaping double quotes within string literals. Hence the triple quotes: the first quote is a quote, the second pair is an escaped quote. They are "the same thing." In a formula, `"1"` will be the string literal  `1` and `"""1"""` will be the string literal `"1"`